# Can constructor return data types in java like methods?

Tags: java, oop

I have a question in java object oriented programming.

Can constructors return data types like methods in java?

Comment: No. Please read  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

> Constructor declarations look like method declarations—except that
>   they use the name of the class and have **no return type**.

Answer (score 2):

Constructors always return an object of the class they belong to, just like specified in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8).

Unlike method return types, the constructor "return type" is implicit.

Comment: Can you provide any docs, saying the constructor returns an object of that class.?

Comment: @Kayaman Except this line **In all other respects, the constructor declaration looks just like a method declaration that has no result** , I didnt see Constructor returns an object. Can you please add the phrase in your answer, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Not according to the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

> Constructor declarations look like method declarations—except that
>   they use the name of the class and have no return type